# opening image in a new window within the same container

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am trying to work out a way to create a page where when the user clicks on an image
it opens up and maintains the other images as options. I might not be crystal clear describing this one but maybe you understand me anyway?

The code could be something like this:

```
 div theContainer {
     background: white;
     box-shadow: 0 0 20px #123
}

p theContent{}

p theContent>img
```

Is it possible doing this with html and css? Or do I need javscript?

Comment: please provide some more explanation

Answer (score 1):

This is called a `modal dialog` or `modal window`. You need JavaScript to do this, but if you look around there are plenty of plug-ins for jQuery that give you this functionality.

See: http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/

Comment: I don´t understand jquery. Is it a language of its own? Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: jQuery, which is written in JavaScript, is a popular add-on for JavaScript that gives you a lot of code shortcuts and handles cross-browser compatibility issues internally so you don't have to worry about them. It has really changed the way JavaScript is used. There is a large support community and a lot of third-party plugins with pre-made things like tool-tips, dialogs, form validation, table sorters, drag-and-drop and fun things like that.

Comment: @JohnnyHankgard JQuery is a library that makes coding in Javascript easier.

Comment: ok thanks guys, im gonna look deeper in to it. what type of language do i need to understand in other words toS be able to implement jQuery? Strictly javascript and html?

Comment: It's all JavaScript + CSS + HTML